# iterate, check a few form values if updated every 2 seconds

Tags: javascript

I'd like to run the below code and check the *if* statements every **2** seconds, continuously; to see if any values have been updated. So wrapping the below around a timed infinite loop of `2000`?

```
    if (value1 > 0 ) { 
        document.getElementById('field_52_116').style.display = "none";

      } else if (value1 == 0 ) { 
//       document.getElementById('rate').style.display = "none";
//       document.getElementById('pay-plans').style.display = "none";
      }
    if (value2 > 0 ) { 
        document.getElementById('field_52_116').style.display = "none";

    } else if (value2 == 0 ) { 
//       document.getElementById('rate').style.display = "none";
//       document.getElementById('pay-plans').style.display = "none";
    }
    if (value3 > 0 ) { 
        document.getElementById('field_52_116').style.display = "none";

      } else if (value3 == 0 ) { 
//       document.getElementById('rate').style.display = "none";
//       document.getElementById('pay-plans').style.display = "none";
      }
    if (value1 && value2 && value3 == 0 ) { 
        document.getElementById('field_52_116').style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('rate').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('pay-plans').style.display = "none";
    }
```

Comment: Wrap these in a function and use `setInterval`?

Comment: Wrap the above code in a function and use `setInterval` to call that function every 2 seconds like `setInterval( myValidateFunction, 2000);`.

Comment: Why not attach `change` event listeners to your form inputs and do something based on that. Saves having a timer.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to trigger a function onchange?

Comment: What are these `value1, value2 and value3`? Simple JS variables?

Comment: I agree with those recommending to use an event handler for this. A timer seems like the wrong way to go about this, unless you have a specific need of checking every two seconds.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap your checks in a function and use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) to run that function every 2 seconds:

```js
function update() {
  var value1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2),
    value2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2),
    value3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
  document.getElementById("values").innerHTML = `Value1: ${value1}, Value2: ${value2}, Value3: ${value3}`;

  if (value1 > 0) {
    document.getElementById('field_52_116').style.display = "none";
  } else if (value1 == 0) {
    document.getElementById('field_52_116').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('field_52_116').style.color = "green";
  }
  if (value2 > 0) {
    document.getElementById('field_52_116').style.display = "none";
  } else if (value2 == 0) {
    document.getElementById('field_52_116').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('field_52_116').style.color = "red";
  }
  if (value3 > 0) {
    document.getElementById('field_52_116').style.display = "none";
  } else if (value3 == 0) {
    document.getElementById('field_52_116').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('field_52_116').style.color = "blue";
  }
  if (value1 && value2 && value3 == 0) {
    document.getElementById('field_52_116').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('rate').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('pay-plans').style.display = "none";
  }
}

setInterval(update, 2000);
```

```css
div {
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<p id="values"></p>
<div id="field_52_116">Field 52 116</div>
<div id="rate">Rate</div>
<div id="pay-plans">Pay plans</div>
```